# Latitude E7440 has corrupted bios

Tags: bios, dell-latitude

So I have a Dell Latitude E7440 and the BIOS is completely corrupted.
As this model is from 2014, there isn't a BIOS recovery option.
By any chance, could anybody let me know what brand of BIOS this laptop has?
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: eBay has a number of quite-low priced postings for that specific model. You would be able to transfer the drive and memory to the new chassis and have a working unit.

Answer (score 0):

There is very little that you can do as the model is quite old.

Contact Del Support and see if they can replace the motherboard or BIOS chip. Doubtful to be sure, but contact them.

Lenovo machines (that I know - numerous) do not support loading prior BIOS. I don't think Dell go backwards either.

So if Dell cannot help, then replace the machine either with a new machine (for Windows 11) or find a used machine of the same model number.

Comment: Seems like it's the case, but in case you didn't know this is a Dell, not a Lenovo.

Comment: I edited my post to make it Dell.   Sorry error on my part. Explanation is the same however.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try removing the CMOS battery for like an hour and experiment to see if the BIOS will come back but I have my doubt. I believe MB manufacurers use specialized equipment to load the first BIOS in the chip.